# How to increment height when width decreases?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the height of a div when the width of the screen decrease below 979px, I would like to do this in the div style tag and not in the CSS file.

```
<div class="slider-item overlay" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
```

```
.slider-item {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    height: calc(100vh);
    min-height: 700px;
    position: relative;

.slider-item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: .3;
```

It should be easy to do (I suppose, I'm not really confident with CSS), but when I had:

```
style="@media (max-width:979px) height:120vw;"
```

in my div tag nothing happens.

Any help is really appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media queries are definied like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 979px)
{

  .slider-item
  {
    height:120vw;
  }

}
```

You will need to set the class you are refering to: in your case that's slider-item

Comment: can I had this in the div tag?

Comment: @Skalfaro You mean my code above? That need to be in a .css file or style tag.